# Разумно ли вместо трудоемкой ручной чистки ПК вернуть его к заводским настройкам?

Tags: linux, windows, файловая-система

Планирую устанавливать линукс рядом с виндой и хочу основательно почистить пк. Весь софт будет использоваться с бута линукса. Но поскольку всего мне нужны 40 гб файлов из 400гб имеющихся на данный момент, думаю просто сохранить их на жестком носителе и вернуть пк к заводским настройкам. Посоветуйте, насколько разумная идея?

Comment: Я своё кино\фотки\музыку нормально храню на ntfs-разделе и монтирую в линукс без проблем. Так что 50 гигов на `/`, 50 на `/home`, остальное - ntfs.

Answer (score 1):

Просто купите ещё один диск и установите туда linux, отключив физически диск с windows. После установки диск с windows подключите обратно. Загружайте желаемую ось выбором загрузочного диска.